# Classification of Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing

Assume I have built a MVC web apps written using Java.

Now I want to write unit tests for the web apps, what kind of unit testings should be done for a normal mvc web apps?

- model testing
- controller testing
- ui testing
- db testing

any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you should write unit tests for  all (model,controller,db) but UI-testing which is considered as [integration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing)

- Web Apps are better tested with [this tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-testing-tools).
- For Swing and SWT are also specialized tools available.

For DB-testing you might want to check DBUnit

[Open-source Testing Tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools)